# Plot distribution of differences between two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, plot, distribution

I have a pandas dataframe, which have columns `A` & `B`

I just want to plot a distribution graph of the percentage of differences between column `A` & `B`

```
        A                B
  1 1.051990e+10    1.051990e+04
  2 1.051990e+10    1.051990e+04
  5 4.841800e+10    1.200000e+10
  8 2.327700e+10    2.716000e+10
  9 1.204900e+10    2.100000e+08
```

Distribution graph will be like, how many records are having 10% of differences, how many are 20% difference

I tried as follows

```
df percCal(x,y):
  return (x-y)*100/x

df['perc'] = df.apply(lambda x: percCal(df['A'], df['B']), axis=1)
```

This is not working, as i'm newbie please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `lambda` operation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (20, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])

def percCal(x,y):
  return (x-y)*100/x
```

Alternatively, just manipulate the columns directly:

```
df1['diff'] = (df1['A'] - df1['B']) * 100 / df1['A']
```

Apply the function and plot:

```
df1['diff'] = percCal(df1['A'], df1['B'])
df1['diff'].plot(kind='density')
```

[image]

Comment: yes that's worked. In my case where i have over 30K rows, on x-axis, scientific notation is coming, how to avoid that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
df['perc'] = (df['A'] - df['B']) *100/df['A']
```

Comment: if `df['A']`can be `NaN` it will be a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def percCal(x,y):
  return (x-y)*100/x

df['perc'] = df.apply(lambda x: percCal(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1)
```

Change `df`in lambda for `x` in this case you are giving the function the data `x`that means you are giving the `percCal`what you have in the row of the data frame and when you use `df`you are giving actually the data frame and the function is returning a data frame not a value. But please check your code, if `x`in the function can be 0 is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you are looking for:

```
# Dummy df
data = [
    [1.051990e+10, 1.051990e+04],
    [1.051990e+10, 1.051990e+04],
    [4.841800e+10, 1.200000e+10],
    [2.327700e+10, 2.716000e+10],
    [1.204900e+10, 2.100000e+08],
]
cols = ['A', 'B']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

# Solution
import seaborn as sns

df2['pct_diff'] = (df2['A'] - df2['B']) / df2['A']
sns.distplot(df2['pct_diff']);
```

Comment: if `df2['A']`can be `NaN` it will be a problem

Comment: True. In that case, you could add `df2['A'] = df2['A'].fillna(0)`